# Запрос mysql

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Пишет

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
     mysql_query("SELECT datacenter.name, datacenter.surname, senderInfo.name_avatar, senderInfo.has_avatar FROM datacenter LEFT JOIN photo AS senderInfo ON datacenter.id = senderInfo.id WHERE datacenter.id_soft = '$id', datacenter.type = '$house'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: А можете показать сам SQL-запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE datacenter.id = '$id' AND datacenter.type = '$house'
```